# Как сделать цикл, который будет сравнивать все значения одним нажатием на кнопку?

Tags: c#, winforms

Суть.

Нажимаем на кнопку, далее

```
Если ЗначениеИзТаблицыЭксель == ЗначениюИзТаблицыБазыДанных
То Удалить строку из ТаблицыЭксель (globalDataTableExcel)
```

Вот код:

```
            foreach (DataRow i in globalDataTableExcel.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataRow j in globalDataTableMySQL.Rows)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < globalDataTableMySQL.Rows.Count; ++x)
                    {
                        string a = i[0].ToString();
                        string b = j[0].ToString();
                        if ((a != null) & b != null)
                        {
                            if (a != b)
                            {
                                i.Delete();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Строк там много, но как, я извиняюсь "залупить" эту операцию, до тех пор, пока не будут проверены все строки? Напрашивается `while...do`.

И еще выползает исключение, только сейчас заметил, тоже не знаю что делать. Тип исключения Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: А сейчас проверяет не все строки?

Comment: Он проверяет и когда условие ```if (a == b) // если равно - удалить из excel эту строку``` срабатывает, строка удаляется и все на этом.

Comment: И еще выползает исключение, только сейчас заметил, тоже не знаю что делать.
Тип исключения ```Object reference not set to an instance of an object.```

Comment: Вместо `foreach` для `dgvMinusator` используйте цикл `for` от конца к началу.

Comment: И вообще, это дубликат вашего предыдущего вопроса.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov и каким образом я сделаю перебор по значениям строк с помощью цикла ```for```?

Answer (score 0):

Решение

```
        private void btnMinusovat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> data_Excel = new List<string>();
            DataBase db = new DataBase(connection_String);
            int iRows = Convert.ToInt32(db.ParseData($"SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM phone1"));

            try
            {
                foreach (DataRow i in globalDataTableExcel.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow j in globalDataTableMySQL.Rows)
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x < globalDataTableMySQL.Rows.Count; ++x)
                        {
                            string a = i[0].ToString();
                            string b = j[0].ToString();
                            if ((a != null) & b != null)
                            {
                                if (a != b)
                                {
                                    i.Delete();
                                    ++minusSlov;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                globalDataTableExcel.AcceptChanges(); 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка: " + ex.Message.ToString(), "Exception " + this.Name);
            }
            finally
            {
                dgvMinusator.DataSource = globalDataTableExcel;
            }
```

Comment: Вы это серьёзно? Это нерабочий код. При удалении одной строки из `dgvMinusator`, следующая пропускается. Код будет работать только если строки, подлежащие удалению, не расположены подряд.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov можете предложить вариант для решения этой проблемы, который будет лучше?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov что если сравнивать две ```DataTable```? И из них удалять строки

Comment: Не важно, что сравнивать. Нужно проходить циклом от конца к началу.

Comment: Можно, в принципе, и от начала к концу, но при удалении элемента корректировать индекс, что невозможно в foreach. Нужно юзать for.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov как в таком случае сравнить строку? Вернее получить ее из таблицы

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov или вы имеете в виду такую структуру: ```for (...) { foreach (...) {}}```

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov попробовал сделать циклом, считывает вроде как адекватно, но возникает исключение (добавлю код в дополнение)

Comment: @byte_ В foreach вместо `dgvMinusator.Rows` попробуйте `dgvMinusator.Rows.Reverse()`. Тоже самое и для `dgvPlusator`. Должно помочь. Да, это не самое эффективное решение, но требует минимального изменения в вашем коде. Если есть цель написать эффективный код - используйте циклы `for` вместо `foreach` с корректировкой индекса, как вам предложил AlexanderPetrov

Comment: @AndreiKhotko я не понимаю как его здесь реализовать, проблема до сих пор актуальна

Comment: @byte_ у вас слишком много вложенных циклов. Должно быть 2 (один - по строкам одной таблицы, другой - по строкам другой таблицы)

Comment: Желательно, чтобы вы привели пример "Вот две таблицы (показать картинкой либо текстом), мне нужно, чтобы на выходе была такая таблица `excel`"

Comment: @AndreiKhotko вкратце: у меня в экселе 2 красных и 1 зеленое яблоко. В таблице mysql 0 красных и 1 зеленое. Я оставляю в экселе только 1 зеленое, а 2 красных удаляю из экселя

Comment: @AndreiKhotko только этих "яблок" что в экселе, что в базе больше 1 млн строк